# ASP.NET MVC: Large file upload issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

This issue is discussed on multiple threads, still I am not able to get it working. I am uploading a text file of size 30MB approximately. I am using a classic approach where `<form>` is having `<input type="file"/>` and form submit is handled by method accepting `HttpPostedFileBase` parameter with `[HttpPost]` attribute.

**Problem:**

1. On Crome it gives ERR_CONNECTION_RESET message after around 2 minutes.
2. On IE, it gives following message:

   HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found
   The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.
3. File upload is taking too long (more than 30 minutes) on Firefox.

**Solution I tried:**
Set `maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600"` in `<httpRuntime>`.

**What I want?**

1. Upload performance should be good.
2. Solution should work for all browsers.

I know even though I get a solution working on all browsers, it is going to take lot of time for uploading. Are there any alternatives to approach I am using so that application performance will be good?

Answer (score 0):

You have changed the request length, but not the content length as IE has suggested.

Try adding

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="36700160" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

to your web.config.

something to note, `maxAllowedContentLength` is measured in Bytes; 36,700,160 Bytes should be roughly equal to about 35MB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a couple of things, firstly, you'll need to alter the maximum file upload size:

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="36700160" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Where `maxAllowedContentLength` is the maximum file size in **bytes**

Secondly, with a file that size, you might need to change the the request timeout limit, as the amount of time taken to upload the file may exceed the default (which I think is around 2 minutes):

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" />
</system.web>
```

Where `executionTimeout` is the length of time in **seconds**

Change these values to what you feel is appropriate for your solution

Comment: I tried adding <security> tag but it's giving following error on IE: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: Did you put `security` inside `system.webServer`